# Why have an empty PHP Variable?

Tags: php, variables

I've been reviewing a lot of PHP code lately and I keep coming across situations like this:

```
function () {

    $var = '';

    if ( ... ) {
      $var = '1';
    }

    echo $var;

}
```

An empty variable is declared and then later defined.

Is there a reason behind this?

The only reason I can think of for doing this is just to make sure `$var` starts out as empty in case it's previously defined.

Comment: It's a preset in this very case, because the second assignment is conditional. `$var` would else resolve to NULL; with a Notice (which this approach is often used for to eschew).

Comment: Try to put "@" before the variable at echo. `echo @$var;` this will by pass the E_NOTICE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don´t define `$var` and the `if` condition fails, you get an `undefined variable $var, assumed constant var` notice. (`E_NOTICE`)

Comment: Not exactly an Error, just a `Notice`. Still should be avoided. Besides, attempting to obtain the value of an undefined variable will get you `null`, not an empty string. This can be relevant depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

If `if ( ... ) {` evaluates to false `$var` will never be defined. So when `echo $var` is executed a `NOTICE` will be displayed that `$var` is not defined. By defining a default value you prevent this situation from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not have the $var = ''; you would then need

```
if (isset($var)) {
    echo $var;
} else {
    echo '';
}
```

This really helps when you are returning something like an AJAX call. You can initialize everything to '' or FALSE. This way, javascript won't error because something it is expecting is always there, even if it is FALSE or blank.